# Python list assignment -- puzzling behavior

Tags: python, list

I am having strange behavior with a list of lists in Python. There are two levels, but depending on how I set up the list, editing one of the levels either edits just the correct element, or all elements that share the 2nd reference.

This can be summarized as follows -- b and c are ititially the same (Python shows they are equivalent). Then I edit them the same way by changing the `[1][1]` entry, however for b, this impacts any entry with 2nd index=1 (ie adding to `b[1][1]` changes `b[2][1]`), where for `c` it only changes `c[1][1]`. This behavior is very puzzling, clearly something in the assignment of `b` relates the indexed entities to each other. Anyone know what is going on?

```
b = 10*[4*[0]]
c = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]];

print(b==c);

b[1][1] += 2;
c[1][1] += 2;

print(b==c);
```

Comment: Be aware that the trailing semicolon `;` after `print` is redundant.

Comment: @wnnmaw That's not the correct dup.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, whoops, careless reading on my part

Comment: List `b` contains ten references to the same list `[0,0,0,0]`, so modifications of any of `b`'s items will affect all of them. Use `b = [4*[0] for i in range(10)]` to resemble the assignment you made to `c`.

Comment: @Stefano Like all of them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I did not see the other `;` at a first glance. Bottom line: no semicolon in Python, please.